/etc/sudoers.d in eagle Linux 32-bit not working
I have 2 Linux systems: 32bit (eagle - 12.1) and 64bit (braswell - 42.2). In 64bit version I have /etc/sudoers.d/user, same as in 32bit also but in 32bit in /etc/sudoers file when I add includedir /etc/sudoers.d line in visudo editor I am getting syntax error which means can I take it as not supported? (question in my mind).
Syntax Error:
root@linux59:~> sudo visudo
sudo: >>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 76 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 76
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

this error is in 32bit
Error while executing serviname start in cmd:
sudo: >>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 76 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 76
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
sudo: >>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 76 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 76
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting

32 bit /etc/sudoers:
# sudoers file.
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# See the sudoers man page for the details on how to write a sudoers file.
#

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# Defaults specification

# Prevent environment variables from influencing programs in an
# unexpected or harmful way (CVE-2005-2959, CVE-2005-4158, CVE-2006-0151)
Defaults always_set_home
Defaults env_reset

Defaults env_keep = "LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS XDG_SESSION_COOKIE"
# Comment out the preceding line and uncomment the following one if you need
# to use special input methods. This may allow users to compromise  the root
# account if they are allowed to run commands without authentication.
#Defaults env_keep = "LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS XDG_SESSION_COOKIE XMODIFIERS GTK_IM_MODULE QT_IM_MODULE QT_IM_SWITCHER"

# In the default (unconfigured) configuration, sudo asks for the root password.
# This allows use of an ordinary user account for administration of a freshly
# installed system. When configuring sudo, delete the two
# following lines:
#Defaults targetpw   # ask for the password of the target user i.e. root
#ALL ALL=(ALL) ALL   # WARNING! Only use this together with 'Defaults targetpw'!

Defaults visiblepw   # needed to make 2root work again. The passwd is not printed on the screen, though.

# Runas alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL) SETENV: ALL

m ALL=(ALL) SETENV:ALL
deviceadm         ALL = (ALL) SETENV: ALL

%nta    ALL=SETENV: NOPASSWD: /Speicherkarte/Unicorn/setAdapter
%nta    ALL=SETENV: NOPASSWD: /Speicherkarte/Unicorn/setGateway
%nta    ALL=SETENV: NOPASSWD: /Speicherkarte/Unicorn/setPCName
%nta    ALL=SETENV: NOPASSWD: /Speicherkarte/Unicorn/test-usbstick
%nta    ALL=SETENV: NOPASSWD: /opt/mt/netconfig/netconfig.pl
%nta    ALL=SETENV: NOPASSWD: /bin/date
%nta    ALL=SETENV: NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/nmb
%nta    ALL=SETENV: NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl
%nta    ALL=SETENV: NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl
%nta    ALL=SETENV: NOPASSWD: /opt/RemoteService/run_remotegui.sh
%nta    ALL=SETENV: NOPASSWD: /sbin/halt
%nta    ALL=SETENV: NOPASSWD: /sbin/hwclock
%nta    ALL=SETENV: NOPASSWD: /sbin/poweroff
%nta    ALL=SETENV: NOPASSWD: /sbin/rcnetwork
%nta    ALL=SETENV: NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot
%nta    ALL=SETENV: NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/smartctl

device   ALL=(deviceadm) NOPASSWD: /opt/mt/noop/startup/run_update
device   ALL=(deviceadm) NOPASSWD: /Speicherkarte/Unicorn/update.sh
m   ALL=SETENV: NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl
m   ALL=SETENV: NOPASSWD: /home/m/service/Services


## Uncomment to allow members of group wheel to execute any command
# %wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL


# Uncomment to allow people in group wheel to run all commands
# and set environment variables.
# %wheel    ALL=(ALL) SETENV: ALL

# Same thing without a password
# %wheel    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: SETENV: ALL
includedir /etc/sudoers.d

and in 64-bit:
## sudoers file.
##
## This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
## Failure to use 'visudo' may result in syntax or file permission errors
## that prevent sudo from running.
##
## See the sudoers man page for the details on how to write a sudoers file.
##

##
## Host alias specification
##
## IP addresses, network numbers or netgroups.
# Host_Alias    WEBSERVERS = www1, www2, www3

##
## User alias specification
##
## Groups of users.  These may consist of user names, uids, Unix groups,
## or netgroups.
# User_Alias    ADMINS = millert, dowdy, mikef

##
## Cmnd alias specification
##
## Groups of commands.  Often used to group related commands together.
# Cmnd_Alias    PROCESSES = /usr/bin/nice, /bin/kill, /usr/bin/renice, \
#               /usr/bin/pkill, /usr/bin/top

##
## Defaults specification
##
## Prevent environment variables from influencing programs in an
## unexpected or harmful way (CVE-2005-2959, CVE-2005-4158, CVE-2006-0151)
Defaults always_set_home
## Path that will be used for every command run from sudo
#Defaults secure_path="/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
#Defaults env_reset
## Change env_reset to !env_reset in previous line to keep all environment variables
## Following list will no longer be necessary after this change

Defaults env_keep = "LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS XDG_SESSION_COOKIE"
## Comment out the preceding line and uncomment the following one if you need
## to use special input methods. This may allow users to compromise  the root
## account if they are allowed to run commands without authentication.
#Defaults env_keep = "LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS XDG_SESSION_COOKIE XMODIFIERS GTK_IM_MODULE QT_IM_MODULE QT_IM_SWITCHER"

## Do not insult users when they enter an incorrect password.
Defaults !insults

##
## Uncomment to enable logging of a command's output, except for
## sudoreplay and reboot.  Use sudoreplay to play back logged sessions.
# Defaults log_output
# Defaults!/usr/bin/sudoreplay !log_output
# Defaults!/sbin/reboot !log_output

## In the default (unconfigured) configuration, sudo asks for the root password.
## This allows use of an ordinary user account for administration of a freshly
## installed system. When configuring sudo, delete the two
## following lines:
Defaults targetpw   # ask for the password of the target user i.e. root
ALL ALL=(ALL) ALL   # WARNING! Only use this together with 'Defaults targetpw'!

##
## Runas alias specification
##

##
## User privilege specification
##
root ALL=(ALL) SETENV: ALL

device ALL=(ALL) SETENV:ALL
deviceadm ALL=(ALL) SETENV: ALL

%nta    ALL=SETENV: NOPASSWD: /Speicherkarte/Unicorn/setAdapter
%nta    ALL=SETENV: NOPASSWD: /Speicherkarte/Unicorn/setGateway
%nta    ALL=SETENV: NOPASSWD: /Speicherkarte/Unicorn/setPCName
%nta    ALL=SETENV: NOPASSWD: /Speicherkarte/Unicorn/test-usbstick
%nta    ALL=SETENV: NOPASSWD: /opt/mt/netconfig/netconfig.pl
%nta    ALL=SETENV: NOPASSWD: /bin/date
%nta    ALL=SETENV: NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/nmb
%nta    ALL=SETENV: NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl
%nta    ALL=SETENV: NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl
%nta    ALL=SETENV: NOPASSWD: /opt/RemoteService/run_remotegui.sh
%nta    ALL=SETENV: NOPASSWD: /sbin/halt
%nta    ALL=SETENV: NOPASSWD: /sbin/hwclock
%nta    ALL=SETENV: NOPASSWD: /sbin/poweroff
%nta    ALL=SETENV: NOPASSWD: /sbin/rcnetwork
%nta    ALL=SETENV: NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot
%nta    ALL=SETENV: NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/smartctl

device   ALL=(deviceadm) NOPASSWD: /opt/mt/noop/startup/run_update
device   ALL=(deviceadm) NOPASSWD: /Speicherkarte/Unicorn/update.sh
device   ALL=SETENV: NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl
device   ALL=SETENV: NOPASSWD: /home/m/service/Services


## Uncomment to allow members of group wheel to execute any command
# %wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL

## Same thing without a password
# %wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

## Read drop-in files from /etc/sudoers.d
## (the '#' here does not indicate a comment)
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
%nta ALL=SETENV: NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/ping

How to make it work is it possible to use /etc/sudoers.d in 32bit version?

“i am getting syntax error”, what error?

sudo: >>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 76 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 76
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
sudo: >>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 76 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 76
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting

root@linux59:~> sudo visudo
sudo: >>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 76 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 76
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
this error is in 32bit

Please, put this in the question, it's unreadable in comments.

Added the error in question.

Preliminary note
I don't know AutoDesk EAGLE at all. I was not able to trace "eagle - 12.1" to see if it's very old, new or what. For this reason the answer is general.

Analysis
See the comment in the second sudoers file you posted:

the '#' here does not indicate a comment

#includedir is the uncommented directive, commented one would be ##includedir. Sole includedir is not recognized, hence the error. Very confusing, I know.
Another confusing directive is #include.
Recent enough sudo supports @includedir and @include, so we can make it far less confusing; but it still supports #includedir and #include for compatibility.

Solution
If you can still edit the sudoers file (e.g. you can log in directly as root), do so and change includedir to #includedir. This should fix the syntax. Verify if sudo works. Verify if files from the directory get included (sudo -l may be useful). According to the changelog sudo has supported #includedir since 2009-04-18. If #includedir is treated as a comment then apparently your sudo is too old and you cannot use #includedir as you intended. (I guess support for #include predates the support for #includedir; if #includedir does not work and you want to include one or few files, try one or few #include lines to include the files one by one, this may still work.)
If #includedir works, consider trying @includedir instead (supported since 2020-05-20): use visudo (sudo visudo if needed) and change #includedir to @includedir. If the tool complains, abort. If the tool does not complain and sudo still works – very well. The point of this step is making this line in sudoers less confusing. Now it's clear @includedir is not commented out, nobody will repeat your mistake.
If you cannot edit the sudoers file because you have locked yourself out from sudo and there is no other easy way, boot in recovery mode (I don't know AutoDesk EAGLE, so I cannot guide you in details) or boot a live distro and fix the file from there.
